# Move Duplicate Rows Unique Value to New Column

Tags: excel, indexing, formula

I have a conundrum and hoping someone can shed some light to help.

I have a file with around 20k rows of account data however for some reason the rows are duplicated because of package service and it looks like this:

Account Name --- Join Date --- Other Columns ---- Package
Account 1 ---------- 1/1/19 ------- Data ----------------- Main Package
Account 1 ---------- 1/1/19 ------- Data ----------------- Bolt On
Account 1 ---------- 1/1/19 ------- Data ----------------- Add on
Account 2 ---------- 1/1/18 ------- Data ----------------- Main Package
Account 3 ---------- 1/1/17 ------- Data ----------------- Main Package
Account 3 ---------- 1/1/17 ------- Data ----------------- Add on
Account 4 ---------- 1/1/19 ------- Data ----------------- Main Package

Is it possible in Excel using some type of INDEX or something where I can create a new tab where there is just one row for each account name then it looks up that column for the Package column and adds the first value then if there are additional matches it puts it in the next column?

So it would look like this:
Account Name ------ Join Date -------- Other Column ------ Main Package ----- Extra Item --- Extra Item
Account 1 -------------- 1/1/19 ------------- Data ---------------- Main Package ----- Bolt On ------- Add On
Account 2 -------------- 1/1/18 ------------- Data ---------------- Main Package
Account 3 -------------- 1/1/17 ------------- Data ---------------- Main Package ----- Add On
Account 4 -------------- 1/1/19 ------------- Data ---------------- Main Package

Is this doable? As you can see I dont need them to organize the columns based on package type I just need this column to move into the row so I only have 1 row for each account.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: `Is this doable?` Yes.  Use Power Pivot or vba.  A formula will be challenging and require that it be an array type and that many will hinder performance.

Comment: This can also be done fairly easily with `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the headers (Account, Join Date, Other Column, Main Package, Extra Item, Extra Item...) in row 1, fill the columns as follows:

**Account**: Either use advanced filter, remove duplicate in-built function, VBA or the following Index + Match function `=IFERROR(INDEX(Source!$A$2:$A$22, MATCH(0, IF(ISBLANK(Source!$A$2:$A$22),1,COUNTIF(Result!$A$1:A1, Source!$A$2:$A$22)), 0)), "")` Enter using Ctrl + Shift + Enter and drag down.

**Join Date & Other Column**: Paste the following formula under Join Column, drag to Other column and drag down to fill. `=IFERROR(INDEX(Source!$A$1:$D$22,  MATCH($A2,Source!$A$1:$A$22,0),  COLUMN()), 0)`

**Main Package and Extra Item**: Enter the formula below under Main Package using Ctrl + Shift + Enter. Drag towards the right to populate the Extra Columns and then drag down to fill. `=IFERROR(INDEX(Source!$A$1:$D$22,   AGGREGATE(15,4, IF(Source!$A$1:$A$22=$A2, ROW(Source!$A$1:$A$22)-ROW(Source!$A$1)+1),    COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$2)-2),   COLUMN(Source!$D$1)), "")`

See the sample workbook at https://1drv.ms/x/s!AklQqQDqhBrtg2LdK1FGM6QX4WG8?e=3GfMMD

Comment: This is great! exactly what needed :) Thanks a million!